# How to prevent babel.js from encoding string to unicode?

Tags: character-encoding, babeljs

**I have a simple function:**

```
const showUTF8Text = text => `Funkcja wyświetla tekst: ${text}`;
```

and after transpile it with babel I receive:

```
var showUTF8Text = function showUTF8Text(text) {
  return "Funkcja wy\uFFFDwietla tekst: " + text;
};
```

how to prevent babel from encoding to keep the original string?

Comment: Note: the problem is not Unicode encoding: Unicode is capable to encode (without losing information) nearly all encodings (nearly: all encoding used when Unicode was established). The FFFD hints some other error, like you told the string was UTF-8 and so to read as UTF-8 when in fact was not UTF-8. Or other mix encoding. Note: web is UTF-8, so I would check the encoding of origin strings

Answer (score 1):

As suggested here: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9804#issuecomment-480075309 
Add this to your babel config:

```json
"generatorOpts": {
  "jsescOption": {
    "minimal": true
  }
}
```

More info about this `jsesc` option on their README: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsesc#minimal